# Format of comment parameters on bitcoind sendfrom command unclear. Attempts result in 'error: type mismatch'

Tags: bitcoind

The way to specify comment and comment-to parameters when calling bitcoind sendfrom at the comment line is not clear.

When using sendtoaddress, this format works:

```
bitcoind sendtoaddress 'sendToBitCoinAddress' '0.42' 'comment' 'comment-to'
```

The man page specifies sendfrom has this format:

```
sendfrom <fromaccount> <tobitcoinaddress> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment] [comment-to]
```

However a similar usage to sendtoaddress results in an error. I've tried various permutations like:

```
bitcoind sendfrom 'testAccount69' 'sendToBitCoinAddress' '0.69' 'comment 'comment-to'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are missing the field "minconf", probably setting that to any value would allow you to call the function properly.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax is a little confusing. What worked for me was:

    `bitcoind sendfrom 'testAccount69' 'sendToBitCoinAddress' '0.69' '1' 'comment 'comment-to'`

Answer (score 2):

The error says 'type mismatch' because you're specifying 'comment' as the value for minconf.  minconf is used to check that the account you're sending from has sufficient funds with the specified number of confirmations.  So minconf needs to be a number.